# ForeignKey and a ManyToMany Self Query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model as follows:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=30)
    categorykey=models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
    categorykey=models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=30)
    relatedcategories=models.ManyToManyField("Category",symmetrical=False)
```

The categories can have related categories. For example, if the category is "Vet", the related categories might be "Animals", "Medicine", etc. I want to find all the Topics within a category and it's related categories.

I can not figure out how to do that, I think I want something like:

```
categorykey="Vet"
topics=list(Topic.objects.filter(categorykey__relatedcategories__in=categorykey))
```

But that just throws an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
topics = Topic.objects.filter(categorykey__relatedcategories__categorykey = 'Vet')
```

Or this:

```
vet_category = Category.objects.get(category_key = 'Vet')
topics = Topic.objects.filter(categorykey__relatedcategories = vet_category)
```

(Depending on which is more convenient for you.)